# How to disable three.js to resize images in power of two?

Tags: three.js, textures

three.js automatically resizes the texture image, if it is not power of two.
In my case am using a custom canvas as texture , which is not power of two.while resizing
makes the texture not appearing properly.Is there any way to disable the resizing of the images in three.js

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*three.js* actually is trying to **do you a favor**.

Since it is open source we can read the source code of [WebGLRenderer.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js) and see that the `setTexture` method calls the (non public visible) method `uploadTexture`.

The latter has this check:

```
if ( textureNeedsPowerOfTwo( texture ) && isPowerOfTwo( image ) === false ){

    image = makePowerOfTwo( image );
}
```

Which is quite explanatory itself.

You may wonder now what `textureNeedsPowerOfTwo` actually checks. Let's see.

```
function textureNeedsPowerOfTwo( texture ) {

        if ( texture.wrapS !== THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping || texture.wrapT !== THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping ) return true;
        if ( texture.minFilter !== THREE.NearestFilter && texture.minFilter !== THREE.LinearFilter ) return true;

        return false;
}
```

If you use *wrapping* for the texture coordinated different from *clamp* or if you use a filtering that is not *nearest* nor *linear* the texture gets scaled.

If you are surprised by this code **I strongly suggest you** to take a look at the [MDN page on using textures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL).

Quoting

> The catch: these textures [Non Power Of Two textures] cannot be used with mipmapping and they must not "repeat" (tile or wrap).
>
> *[...]*
>
> Without performing the above configuration, WebGL requires all samples of NPOT [Non Power Of Two] textures to fail by returning solid black: rgba(0,0,0,1).

So using a NPOT texture with **incorrect texture parameters** would give you the good old **solid black**.

---

Since *three.js* is open source, you can edit your local copy and remove the "offending" check.

However a better, simpler, and more maintainable approach is to simply scale the *UV* mapping.  After all it is there just for this use case.

Comment: Nicely answered. :)