# Texture loads as a solid color in three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm trying to apply a texture to a 3d object in react-three-renderer. The texture seems to be loaded properly, but when it applies it to the object it only seems to be reading a single pixel from the image, so the entire object is a single color. This is what my render method looks like for the object:

```
render: function () {
this.props.member.geometry.transformationMatrix.decompose(
  this._internals.position,
  this._internals.rotation,
  this._internals.scale);

return <object3D ref={_.set.bind(this, this, 'rootObject')}>
  <mesh
    position={this._internals.position}
    quaternion={this._internals.rotation}
    scale={this._internals.scale}
    name={_.uniqueId('member-')}
    ref={_.set.bind(this, this, 'mesh')}>
    <geometry
      vertices={this.props.member.geometry.vertices}
      faces={this.props.member.geometry.faces}/>
    <meshBasicMaterial>
        <texture
          url='assets/flag.png'
        />
    </meshBasicMaterial>
  </mesh>
</object3D>
}
```

The image that I'm using for the flag is this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Vertical_United_States_Flag.svg/2000px-Vertical_United_States_Flag.svg.png

I've tried different images and they seem to be reading the bottom left pixel of the image, so the flag image makes my 3d objects red.

My console output says:

```
THREE.XHRLoader: HTTP Status 0 received.
lib.js:667 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (2000x3800). Resized to 2048x4096 <img src=​"blob:​file%3A/​/​/​d6c9cae3-aa01-4c8d-b409-4c7b7ccb27d0">​
lib.js:667 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (2000x3800). Resized to 2048x4096 <img src=​"blob:​file%3A/​/​/​252c94cb-2de1-4b80-8e52-1d1f4b3670b4">​
lib.js:667 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (2000x3800). Resized to 2048x4096 <img src=​"blob:​file%3A/​/​/​84bdac61-7922-4415-8b18-e7342c98bcf1">​
lib.js:667 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (2000x3800). Resized to 2048x4096 <img src=​"blob:​file%3A/​/​/​816d95cc-d2f2-45b0-b23c-44f90eda4fb4">​
lib.js:667 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (2000x3800). Resized to 2048x4096 <img src=​"blob:​file%3A/​/​/​3409d1b1-8b1b-48bf-a50e-ed12a3a938df">​
lib.js:667 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (2000x3800). Resized to 2048x4096 <img src=​"blob:​file%3A/​/​/​9ea60ad1-42a1-4bd5-a149-7a87771fad8c">​
```

Is there a reason it's doing this? I have very little experience with three.js so I don't even know where to start looking. Could it be a setting of my renderer or is it something else?

Comment: Sounds like something with your matrices is wrong.
Also check this for the Texture warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059642/how-to-disable-three-js-to-resize-images-in-power-of-two

Comment: most probably the texture component is not setting the correct size of the image.