# suppress three.js image is not power of two warning

Tags: three.js

i'm using three.js version 92 with use of texture.

[three.js warn demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCdF5.png)

thanks to three.js i've the transformation of image's dimension in power of two automaticly, but i would like to suppress the warn that it show in the console without remove all the other warn from other modules or functions. 
i would hide the three.js for my users, but i would like to use the rest of them from other libs.

is there a way to set the texture loader to hide them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable three.js to resize images in power of two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059642/how-to-disable-three-js-to-resize-images-in-power-of-two)

Comment: @Mugen87 I think they're okay with the resizing, they just want to suppress the message.

Comment: The easiest way is to just edit the message out of three.js. Search for the string in the code, and you should find it rather easily.

Comment: @TheJim01 i'm installing three.js with npm so i don't want to alterate the code in node_modules, otherwise i need to do that also on computers of my colleagues, and when i need to upadte three.js i have to do that again and again.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

**The first and easiest** is to remove the `console.warn` line from three.js. You've said that's not feasible due to how you acquire three.js, but there are other ways.

**The next is to override the code** where the warning is occurring. This warning (and there are several places where it can occur) happens in the `WebGLRenderer` object.

1. Download the THREE.js source.
2. Open in `threejs/build/three.js` in an editor.
3. Find the `WebGLRenderer`.
4. Copy that whole function into a JavaScript file you control.
5. Edit that new file to remove those console warnings.
6. Reference the new file in your project.
7. In the code where you interact with the `THREE` namespace, but before you create the `WebGLRenderer` object, replace `THREE.WebGLRenderer` like this:

`THREE.WebGLRenderer = WebGLRenderer;`

The reference to `WebGLRenderer` on the left is to the loaded `THREE` namespace. The reference to `WebGLRenderer` on the right is to the one from the new file (with the warnings removed).

**Finally, you can just disable warnings entirely.** This warning *should* only appear during the first `renderer.render` call when the texture is available. I personally don't recommend doing this unless you're comfortable with losing all console warnings in the interim between when you turn warnings off, and whenever the texture finishes loading. That would go something like this:

```
var originalWarning = console.warn; // back up the original method
console.warn = function(){}; // now warnings do nothing!

var tex = texLoader.load("texture.png", functon(){
  renderer.render(scene, camera); // sends the texture to the GPU
  console.warn = originalWarning; // turns warnings back on
});

var mat = new THREE.SomeMaterial({
  map: tex
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, this could be a solution, the only think is that i need to change the source code of threel.js, and i don't like to do this.