# Three.js: THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (1600x900). Resized to 1024x512

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently learning three.js. I wanna display a 16x9 photo in my scene.

This is the code for adding an Array of `images` to my scene:

```
  const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: loader.load(images[i]),
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 1,
  });
  const plane = new Mesh(new PlaneGeometry(imageWidth, 45), material);
  plane.overdraw = true;
  plane.position.x = i * (imageWidth + imageOffset);
  plane.position.y = 0;
  this.introImages.push({
    obj: plane,
    round: 1,
  });
  this.introImagesGroup.add(this.introImages[i].obj);
```

Now I'm getting the console warning:

> THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (1600x900). Resized to 1024x512

I have read that texture dimensions should be *the power of two* so it can be put into memory in an optimized way which makes me think if the way I'm putting my images in the scene is the *correct way* or if there is another way of putting images that don't follow this in three.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable three.js to resize images in power of two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059642/how-to-disable-three-js-to-resize-images-in-power-of-two)

Comment: @UberMario I don't think that's a duplicate as I understand why the warning appears and I also don't want to disable the warning, I'm more wanting to know if there are other ways to add a photo to a secene other than adding it as a texture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want THREE.js to scale **down** your image, because you'd be losing resolution, so you want to scale it up to the next ^2. You have two options:

1. You could scale up your image and export it at a ^2 resolution `2048 x 1024` in your favorite photo editor.
2. You could dynamically generate a `2048 x 1024` canvas, draw the image onto it scaled up, and use that canvas as your texture source:

   ```
   var imgURL = "path/to/whatever.jpg";

   // Create image element
   const image = document.createElement('img');
   image.src = imgURL;

   // Once image is loaded
   image.onload = () => {
       // Create canvas, size it to ^2 dimensions
       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       canvas.width = 2048;
       canvas.height = 1024;

       // Draw image on canvas, scaled to fit
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 2048, 1024);

       // Create texture
       var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
   };
   ```

Then you can assign that `texture` variable to whatever material you want, and Three.js won't complain.

## Edit:

If you want to avoid texture re-sizing, you could just change your `texture.minFilter` to `THREE.NearestFilter` or `THREE.LinearFilter`, and the engine won't give you warnings. The problem with doing this is that your textures could look grainy or aliased when scaled down, since they won't be [Mipmapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap)

This could be the result you like, or it could look bad, depending on your project. You could see the effects of using `NearestFilter` in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=filter#webgl_materials_texture_filters

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation - my question was more aimed at displaying a picture that has not "power of two" dimensions or if this is considered bad in any scenario, sorry if I was not clear

Comment: Ok, I added an edit to my answer that explains the pros/cons of displaying a picture that's not ^2. There's no right or wrong with this one, it's only whether you like the results or not.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, will read through the documentation now about the different values possible

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that texture dimensions should be the power of two so it can be put into memory in an optimized way which makes me think if the way I'm putting my images in the scene is the correct way or if there is another way of putting images that don't follow this in three.js?

In WebGL 1 you need POT textures for mipmapping. The mentioned warning disappears if you set the `.minFilter` property of your canvas texture to `THREE.LinearFilter`. Keep in mind that using mipmaps is not necessary for all scenarios.